# Setting dynamic height for UITableViewCell with only image (variable height) inside it

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UITableView whose cells will only contain images of variable heights, I set the row height dynamically according to image, it doesnt work perfectly, the images while scrolling sometimes get overlapped.Heres the code...

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [artistfeeds count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[self.newsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"artistFeedCell"];

    UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:((ESArtistFeedObject*)[artistfeeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]).image];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
    [cell.contentView sizeToFit];
    return  cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat height=((ESArtistFeedObject*)[artistfeeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]).image.size.height;
    NSLog(@"section: %i, image height: %f",indexPath.section,height);
    return height;
}

-(void)artistFeedFound:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    //NSLog(@"%@",[notification userInfo]);
    artistfeeds=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if([[[[notification userInfo]objectForKey:@"artistfeed"]objectForKey:@"artist"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        for(NSDictionary *tempDict in [[[notification userInfo]objectForKey:@"artistfeed"]objectForKey:@"artist"])
        {
            ESArtistFeedObject *artistFeed=[[ESArtistFeedObject alloc]init];
            artistFeed.name=[tempDict objectForKey:@"name"];
            artistFeed.type=[tempDict objectForKey:@"postType"];
            artistFeed.desc=[tempDict objectForKey:@"postDesc"];
            if(![artistFeed.type isEqualToString:@"photo"])
                artistFeed.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://c0364947.cdn2.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/%@",[tempDict objectForKey:@"artist_image"]]]]];
            else
                artistFeed.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[tempDict objectForKey:@"photo"]]]];
            [artistfeeds addObject:artistFeed];
        }
    }
    [self.newsTableView reloadData];

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is image being properly initialized inside the objects? Might need to see some more code, because the code you've shown looks to be fine.

Comment: @K.Hole I have added more code, have a look

Comment: where do you create the cells?

Comment: yes where is the code, please post it

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith already have

Comment: where is your UITableViewCell alloc?

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith I'm using ios 5 and storyboards. I use this way to initialize n reuse cells all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath that actually creates cells when there are none to reuse.

```
//assuming there is a class property `int cellImageTag = 100;`
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[self.newsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"artistFeedCell"];
    UIImageView *imgView;
    if(cell == nil)
    {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"artistFeedCell"];
      imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
      imgView.tag = cellImageTag;
      [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
    }
    else
    {
      imgView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:cellImageTag];
    }
    imgView.image = ((ESArtistFeedObject*)[artistfeeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]).image;
    [cell.contentView sizeToFit];
    return  cell;
}
```

**edit:** missed the comment about storyboards

**edit2:** I think this is caused by you creating and adding a new UIImageView subview every time you load a cell. I'm not sure how Storyboards handle re-use of cells but in general your class would have a tag ivar or constant to keep track of the tag of the views you want to re-use within the cells. Updating my code as an example.

**edit3:** The code that follows should be working for storyboards

```
//assuming there is a class property `int cellImageTag = 100;`
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[self.newsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"artistFeedCell"];
    UIImageView *imgView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:cellImageTag];
    if(!imgView)
    {
      imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
      imgView.tag = cellImageTag;
      [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
    }
    imgView.image = ((ESArtistFeedObject*)[artistfeeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]).image;
    [cell.contentView sizeToFit];
    return  cell;
}
```

Comment: I used your code, it always jumps to the else part, the imageView is never initialized.

Comment: the problem is that you're using storyboards. The cell is loaded from the storyboard interface file and is therefore never nil. I am adding an alternate function for storyboards that should work.

Comment: Thanks man, but I got it to work yesterday, I made a custom cell with an imageVIEW outlet inside it, accessed it on cellForRow adn adjusted the frames accordingly. Now it scrolls smooth :)