# Most optimum way to add views in a Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have seen a lot of examples and I cannot find the best answer.

Imagine that I have a custom cell with a 120 height, with 3 UILabels and a UIImageView.

I init my cell with

```
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

Of all the approaches, which one its the most optimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best answer for creating custom tables is at the link below, if you then have specific questions about the code you see there, then feel free to ask more questions.

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Prototype Cell"];
    UILabel *label;
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"Prototype Cell"];
        label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.tag = LABEL_TAG;  //Suppose LABEL_TAG is defined someplace else
        [cell.contentView addSubview: label];
    }
    else 
    {
        label = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:LABEL_TAG];
    }


    label.text = @"Hello World";

    //Suppose you want the label at x coordinate 50
    label.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,120); 

    //Follow similar steps for all of your subviews

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with this code: you will leak memory every time you reuse a cell because you are creating a new label and adding it to the cell each time. The new label should only be created for a new cell, and then given a tag that you can reference when you reuse cells. See my answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189351/setting-dynamic-height-for-uitableviewcell-with-only-image-variable-height-ins/11192701#11192701) question.

Comment: I think there is a serial down voter here.  That is a simple copy past of code at the link I provided.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom UITableviewCell by subclassing the UITableViewCell & overide the method initWithStyle.You can alloc the labels in this init method & also add this label in the cell in this method.

You can also create the UItableViewCell by using nib files.

http://ijoshsmith.com/2011/07/16/creating-a-custom-uitableviewcell-in-ios-4/